# Do these properties imply $f(x)<g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Do these three properties imply $f(x)<g(x) \space \text{for} \space x\geq a$?

If so, can a name be given to this result?

1) $0<f(a)<g(a)$

2) $0>f'(x)>g'(x) \space \text{for} \space x\geq a$

3) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:  Let $F(x)=f(x)-g(x)$.  Then $F(a)\lt0$, $F'(x)\gt0$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=0$.  Can $F$ ever be positive?